# Reference to type 'AuthenticationOptions' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication', but it could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to run 'UseIdentityServerAuthentication' and pass in IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions and get this error in Asp.Net Core 2.

Looking online it appears this was on the roadmap for Asp.Net Core 2 Preview 2, I'm running the latest release version of it so I thought it would be available by now.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is `IdentityOptions`, available at https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/eb3ff7fc32dbfff65a1ba6dfdca16487e0f6fc41/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/IdentityOptions.cs. It should be available in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity Nuget package.

Comment: Ah actually the functrion UseidentityServerAuthentication takes in an identityServerAuthenticationOptions class. Unless I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: My fault! So, you are using IdentityServer4, that was not obvious from your description! So, the package you want is IdentityServer4, it has this type, see https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions.cs.

Comment: There's an open issue about getting this ported to ASP.NET Core 2 here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/issues/72.