# After successful signin with signin manager user is still shown as signed out?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have added the Asp.Net identity framework to a WebAPI which I call from a front end.

After registering an account (and seeing it appear correctly in the database) I sign in with that users username and password, the result is success but the user is not signed in according to the sign in manager?

I've tried using cookie authentication using this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x (adding the code snippets to the webapi) and running this on sign in which happens in a WebAPI controller action:

```
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync
                                           (username, password,
                                             true, false); //succeeded
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyCookieAuthenticationScheme", User);
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase#Properties) for `BaseController` explains that the `User` property:

> Gets or sets the System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal for user associated with the executing action.

This suggests that `User` is determined ahead of the action being executed and therefore simply represents the user that first initiated the request (which most likely will be an authenticated user if you're using password sign ins).

In a Github [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1131) that revolves around a similar scenario, David Fowler explains that:

> ...the sign in operation doesn't change the current request user principal. That only happens on incoming requests once the cookie or bearer token (or whatever thing the type of auth requires to create an identity) is set.

The fact that `IdentityResult.Succeeded` is `true` should be enough to verify that the user has been signed in, as this will only be `false` when the sign in operation fails. If you want to do further processing using the `User` property after a successful sign in, I suggest you redirect to another action, whereby this next request would include the user's sign-in information.

Comment: I should add that the user accounts are being managed on a WebAPI separate to the calling frontend, maybe this affects its behaviour?

Comment: Are you using Cookie authentication or have you git something like a Bearer token?

Comment: Ah no, is this something I should be thinking about? I was going off some examples online. I looked a bit at cookie authentication but wasn't sure if twas something I should go down.

I'd rather use OAuth2 authentication but I've had a tonne of problems with that, not least of which this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997634/reference-to-type-authenticationoptions-claims-it-is-defined-in-microsoft-asp

Comment: ok following from your advice I tried to add cookie authentication but still no luck, I've updated my question to reflect this. I think I'm just doing it wrong really...

Comment: Is this something you can demonstrate in a GitHub repo, for example? I'd be happy to take a look at something there if this isn't a company project, etc.

Comment: This looks like it could be a useful series of posts: https://pioneercode.com/post/authentication-in-a-asp-dot-net-core-api-part-1-identity-access-denied.

Comment: make sure you have included `app.UseAuthentication()` inside startup.cs

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a call to `app.UseAuthentication()` was missing.