# Not able to read identity claims immediately after IAuthenticationService.SignInSync

Tags: c#, authentication, claims-based-identity, claims, httpcookie

I have a method of sign in like this, where I am adding three claims out of which one is custom claim

```
public async Task SignInAsync(IUser user)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString("N")),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, $"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}"),
        new Claim(ClaimsPrincipalHelper.LoginSessionIdClaimsType, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    };

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        AllowRefresh = true,
        IsPersistent = true,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
    };

    await _authenticationService.SignInAsync(_context, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, properties);
}
```

What my understanding is that as soon as this method is called the claims are available to be fetched, so basically after this line

```
await SignInAsync(user);
```

When I will do this immediately

```
var claims = HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList();
```

all the three claims should be available. But this is not the case, it returns zero claims when I do it immediately, but when I try to access the claims after some time then I get all the three claims.

So is it that cookie writing takes time or what?
Why the claims are not available immediately or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: The claims aren't available until the next request from that user. The claims are _read_ from the cookie when a request comes in. `SignInAsync` doesn't refresh these claims.

Comment: @KirkLarkin - Oh Ok! So is there any way to like refresh it without sending the another call? Like force read the cookie?

Comment: There might be _a_ way, but it's not designed for that. Typically, you'll need to return a redirect to another action and do the work you need there. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018437/after-successful-signin-with-signin-manager-user-is-still-shown-as-signed-out/46021394#46021394) where I explain it a little bit more than I can in comments.

Comment: @KirkLarkin - Thank you very much Kirk! Your explanation saved me :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom claim has to Implement `IClaimsTransformation` interface and the `TransformAsync` function, this gets called automatically by ASP. Then it needs to be added to application services collection in the `Startup.cs` class, now you will have access to it.

> Step 1: Implement the interface `IClaimsTransformation` for your.. `MyCustomClaim`

> Step 2: register in your services collection `services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, MyCustomClaim>();`

You need them both or it will return null, here is a nice [ref](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/11/01/authorization-claims.aspx).