# How to get user claims in the same sign-in action in asp.net core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Now, I am working on asp.net core app (core 5).
I try to get the user's claims immediately after signin, but it was empty!
Any idea?

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> LoginUserName(LoginUserNameViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                HttpContext.User.HasClaim("level", "t1"); // <--- got nothing
                var userClaims = User.Claims;  // < --- got nothing
```

Comment: At minimum, you're going to need to include some code to show us how you're trying to retrieve your claims currently, and ideally how you're signing in your user as well. While you're at it, I'd revisit the tags used; as is, many of these aren't specific, if even relevant.

Comment: Search MS documentation (or Google) for ClaimsPrincipal. Follow some examples. If you run into trouble - *then* ask questions

Comment: The claims aren't "refreshed" until the next request for the affected user. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018437/after-successful-signin-with-signin-manager-user-is-still-shown-as-signed-out/46021394#46021394) where I go into a bit more detail.

Comment: @serpent5 is right: `PasswordSignInAsync` only sets the cookie, so that the *next* request comes in authenticated, not the current request. So you won't be able to access the current user like that. But since you actually know the user, you can fetch its claims directly from the user manager: `await usermanager.GetClaimsAsync(user)`

Comment: @abdusco thank you too, is the **GetClaimsAsync(user)** work if use IdentityServer4?

Comment: Yes, you can use the usermanager.GetClaimsAsync(user) method to get the claims in your application (with the identity server 4). And, you can also get the claims via the dbcontext (access the AspNetUserClaims table). Besides, here is an article about using identity server 4, you can refer to it: [EXTENDING IDENTITY IN IDENTITYSERVER4 TO MANAGE USERS IN ASP.NET CORE](https://damienbod.com/2016/11/18/extending-identity-in-identityserver4-to-manage-users-in-asp-net-core/).